# how to float a DIV over FLASH without control over the embedding

Tags: css, flash, layout, html

I'm loading a toolbar that goes over the content of a website that is reviewed. The toolbar has some information we can fill in about the website we're reviewing. There is a problem when there's flash embedded in the original page. Our toolbar will show up behind the flash movie, so we can't use the toolbar as intended. Since we don't have control over the page that is loaded we can not alter the settings of the embedded video.

The question is: how can we make the DIV appear floating above the FLASH even though we don't have control over the embedded flash object?

Answer (score 3):

In your embed and oobject tags you need to add `wmode="transparent"`. Then HTML elements will appear "on top" of the flash object.

Comment: "Since we don't have control over the page that is loaded we can not alter the settings of the embedded video"

Comment: You can walk the dom, find the object/embed tag that's embedding the flash file, and change its properties.

Answer (score 3):

Adding wmode transparent to the flash object can be done in two ways.

Javascript:

```
swfObject.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
```

HTML:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
```

Comment: "Since we don't have control over the page that is loaded we can not alter the settings of the embedded video"

so this is not an option...